# Splitting a tree into two trees of equal size

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that $T=(V,E)$ is a tree graph. Is it always possible to split the tree into two even-sized subgraphs (such that each of them is a tree), each of size $\frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even or of sizes $\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}-1$ if $n$ is odd? If so, how do we prove this?

Comment: Hey. I wonder what properties the "cuts" should have. Should the two sets that you split the tree graph into themselves be trees? Otherwise you can just choose some collection of $\frac{n}{2}$ points in the original tree and declare that they make up one group of your partition.

Comment: They should be a tree, yes

Comment: Although a bit pointless, you can prove the weaker statement about forests instead.  The proof is trivial since the only requirement to being a forest is to have no cycles and any subgraph of an acyclic graph will again have no cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always possible. Take the following tree:

[image]

It has $4$ nodes, but you can't pick any two nodes, such that both the two chosen nodes and the two non-chosen nodes make up trees.

Indeed, if neither of the two nodes you choose is the center node, then the choice will give rise to a disconnected graph (trees must be connected).

If one of the nodes you choose is the center node, then the two nodes you don't choose will again end up in the situation above, where they make up a disconnected graph.

Comment: I was about to post the exact same thing! arrgh!

Comment: @ForeverMozart :( I know the feeling